# What's the term for untapped capacity or inventory that is brought to market by rising prices?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I want to answer [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6585/corny-kegs-do-they-have-a-future) on Homebrew.SE, but I'm at an uncharacteristic loss for words.

One example of the concept I'm trying to describe is gold that had heretofore been sitting in people's jewelry boxes or bottom drawers. With skyrocketing prices, more people became more aware that they were sitting on a valuable resource, and thus [brought that resource to market](http://www.knoxnews.com/news/2011/aug/12/soaring-gold-prices-bring-out-sellers/).

For some reason, my brain is trapped on the metaphor of **dark matter**, which is not apt.

What would you call that untapped inventory? "Untapped inventory"?

Comment: Why get hung up with the word "inventory"? *Untapped reserves, untapped resources, realisable assets*, etc. are all far more common expressions. Much depends on context, obviously, but only commercial organisations would have *inventories* in the first place. Anyone can have *unrealised assets* in the attic or a bottom drawer.

Comment: I'm not hung up on the word "inventory". It's just the only one my brain can come up with at the moment. "Reserves" is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with *untapped reserves*.

For what it's worth, *untapped inventory* does in fact appear to be used in just such a sense.  I [googled](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22untapped+inventory%22) it for a cursory confirmation, and came up with a considerable [438 results](http://www.google.com/#q=%22untapped+inventory%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&psj=1&ei=6gJZT9uNK6LB0QGErLi7Dw&start=431&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&biw=807&bih=281), most of which apply to this context.

However, *untapped reserves* rings truer to my ear, and Google comes up with [885 results](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#q=%22untapped%20reserves%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=OAVZT5ylBqbh0QHzrcTADw&start=875&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&ix=sea&ion=1&biw=807&bih=281).  Though *[untapped resources](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#q=%22untapped%20resources%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=5QZZT5-GEcjj0QHusciRBA&start=973&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=95e6f5d098e4da22&ix=sea&ion=1&biw=807&bih=281)* is even more common, it often means something slightly different - describing more of an ignored type of resource than an hidden stash of a popular type of resource.  (E.g. a secret gold stash would be untapped reserves, but palladium might be an untapped resource.)

Comment: "Untapped reserves" is good, but could apply to something like the Strategic Petroleum Reserve, which we know about and just haven't tapped. I'm looking for something that the holder does not know has increased in value, which is brought to market by that increase.

Comment: You could consider *unrealized reserves* or *unrealized assets*, as FumbleFingers suggests above.  It's stronger on that point, but you can still use *unrealized* to refer to assets/reserves you already know about, but simply haven't made full profit from. Google shows 267 results for the former and 784 for the latter.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a specific term only for reserves which are not even known to exist.  I suspect it's probably because that specific concept isn't an important one in economics; the broader term *untapped reserves* (and the rest) will suit economists quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns for the inventory could be:

- Cache (means hidden supply)
- Stockpile
- Repository
- Hoard

But you wanted a word for the act of bringing the item to market. Maybe *trade in* or simply *sell*.